# How can I rearrange spaces between buttons after changing their size?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, resize

Let's say I have precisely arranged my buttons into a square grid using snaplines, and now there is small space between buttons.

Now, when I change size of all buttons at once, the spacing is not going to be preserved (it will increase or decrease, depending on change of size).

Is there a simple way I could "shake" the buttons so they space from each other again?

Answer (score -1):

I think i didn't really understood it but try to use arrows and shift, with the arrows you can move pixel x pixel the button position and if you press shift & arrows you can resize it...